# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY _TypeError was thrown building Login(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _LoginState#d5ed7):

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-layout-weight

When i run my taxi flutter app the facing this issue

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building Login(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state:
_LoginState#d5ed7):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Login
  Login:file:///E:/Git/FworldAllFiles/tagxi-23/codecanyon-37567287-tagxi-flutter-complete-taxi-booking-solution/main-file-nov-11/tagxi_envato_user/tagxi_envato_use
  r/flutter-user/lib/pages/language/languages.dart:30:64
```

Login.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/pages/loadingPage/loading.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/pages/login/otp_page.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/pages/noInternet/nointernet.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/translations/translation.dart';
import '../../styles/styles.dart';
import '../../functions/functions.dart';
import '../../widgets/widgets.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

//code as int for getting phone dial code of choosen country
String phnumber = ''; // phone number as string entered in input field
// String phone = '';

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  bool terms = true; //terms and conditions true or false
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    countryCode();
    super.initState();
  }

  countryCode() async {
    var result = await getCountryCode();
    if (result == 'success') {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  //navigate
  navigate() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Otp()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Material(
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: (languageDirection == 'rtl')
            ? TextDirection.rtl
            : TextDirection.ltr,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            (countries.isNotEmpty)
                ? Container(
                    color: page,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                        left: media.width * 0.08,
                        right: media.width * 0.08),
                    height: media.height * 1,
                    width: media.width * 1,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: media.height * 0.195),
                        Text(
                          languages[choosenLanguage]['text_login'],
                          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                              fontSize: media.width * twentysix,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: textColor),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: media.height * 0.159,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                          height: 55,
                          width: media.width * 1 - (media.width * 0.08 * 2),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border:
                                  Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: underline))),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  if (countries.isNotEmpty) {
                                    //dialod box for select country for dial code
                                    await showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          var searchVal = '';
                                          return AlertDialog(
                                            insetPadding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            content: StatefulBuilder(
                                                builder: (context, setState) {
                                              return Container(
                                                width: media.width * 0.9,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                child: Directionality(
                                                  textDirection:
                                                      (languageDirection ==
                                                              'rtl')
                                                          ? TextDirection.rtl
                                                          : TextDirection.ltr,
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Container(
                                                        padding:
                                                            const EdgeInsets
                                                                    .only(
                                                                left: 20,
                                                                right: 20),
                                                        height: 40,
                                                        width:
                                                            media.width * 0.9,
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                BorderRadius
                                                                    .circular(
                                                                        20),
                                                            border: Border.all(
                                                                color:
                                                                    Colors.grey,
                                                                width: 1.5)),
                                                        child: TextField(
                                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                              contentPadding: (languageDirection ==
                                                                      'rtl')
                                                                  ? EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                      bottom: media.width *
                                                                          0.035)
                                                                  : EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                      bottom: media.width *
                                                                          0.04),
                                                              border: InputBorder
                                                                  .none,
                                                              hintText:
                                                                  languages[choosenLanguage]
                                                                      [
                                                                      'text_search'],
                                                              hintStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                                                  fontSize: media
                                                                          .width *
                                                                      sixteen)),
                                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              searchVal = val;
                                                            });
                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      const SizedBox(
                                                          height: 20),
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child:
                                                            SingleChildScrollView(
                                                          child: Column(
                                                            children: countries
                                                                .asMap()
                                                                .map(
                                                                    (i, value) {
                                                                  return MapEntry(
                                                                      i,
                                                                      SizedBox(
                                                                        width: media.width *
                                                                            0.9,
                                                                        child: (searchVal == '' &&
                                                                                countries[i]['flag'] != null)
                                                                            ? InkWell(
                                                                                onTap: () {
                                                                                  setState(() {
                                                                                    phcode = i.toString();
                                                                                  });
                                                                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                                                                },
                                                                                child: Container(
                                                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                                                  child: Row(
                                                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                                                    children: [
                                                                                      Row(
                                                                                        children: [
                                                                                          Image.network(countries[i]['flag']),
                                                                                          SizedBox(
                                                                                            width: media.width * 0.02,
                                                                                          ),
                                                                                          SizedBox(
                                                                                              width: media.width * 0.4,
                                                                                              child: Text(
                                                                                                countries[i]['name'],
                                                                                                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: media.width * sixteen),
                                                                                              )),
                                                                                        ],
                                                                                      ),
                                                                                      Text(
                                                                                        countries[i]['dial_code'],
                                                                                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: media.width * sixteen),
                                                                                      )
                                                                                    ],
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                ))
                                                                            : (countries[i]['flag'] != null && countries[i]['name'].toLowerCase().contains(searchVal.toLowerCase()))
                                                                                ? InkWell(
                                                                                    onTap: () {
                                                                                      setState(() {
                                                                                        phcode = i.toString();
                                                                                      });
                                                                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    child: Container(
                                                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                                                      child: Row(
                                                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                                                        children: [
                                                                                          Row(
                                                                                            children: [
                                                                                              Image.network(countries[i]['flag']),
                                                                                              SizedBox(
                                                                                                width: media.width * 0.02,
                                                                                              ),
                                                                                              SizedBox(
                                                                                                  width: media.width * 0.4,
                                                                                                  child: Text(
                                                                                                    countries[i]['name'],
                                                                                                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: media.width * sixteen),
                                                                                                  )),
                                                                                            ],
                                                                                          ),
                                                                                          Text(
                                                                                            countries[i]['dial_code'],
                                                                                            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: media.width * sixteen),
                                                                                          )
                                                                                        ],
                                                                                      ),
                                                                                    ))
                                                                                : Container(),
                                                                      ));
                                                                })
                                                                .values
                                                                .toList(),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }),
                                          );
                                        });
                                  } else {
                                    getCountryCode();
                                  }
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                                //input field
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Image.network(countries[phcode]['flag']),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: media.width * 0.02,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        countries[phcode]['dial_code']
                                            .toString(),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                            fontSize: media.width * sixteen,
                                            color: textColor),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        width: 2,
                                      ),
                                      const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 4),
                              Container(
                                width: 1,
                                height: media.width * 0.0693,
                                color: buttonColor,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: media.width * 0.5,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: controller,
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      phnumber = controller.text;
                                    });
                                    if (controller.text.length ==
                                        countries[phcode]['dial_max_length']) {
                                      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus
                                          ?.unfocus();
                                    }
                                  },
                                  maxLength: countries[phcode]
                                      ['dial_max_length'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                      fontSize: media.width * sixteen,
                                      color: textColor,
                                      letterSpacing: 1),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: languages[choosenLanguage]
                                        ['text_phone_number'],
                                    counterText: '',
                                    hintStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                        fontSize: media.width * sixteen,
                                        color: textColor.withOpacity(0.7)),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

language.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/pages/loadingPage/loading.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/pages/login/login.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/styles/styles.dart';
import 'package:tagyourtaxi_driver/translations/translation.dart';
import '../../functions/functions.dart';
import '../../widgets/widgets.dart';

class Languages extends StatefulWidget {
  const Languages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Languages> createState() => _LanguagesState();
}

class _LanguagesState extends State<Languages> {

  bool _isLoading = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    choosenLanguage = 'en';
    languageDirection = 'ltr';
    super.initState();
  }

//navigate
  navigate() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Login()));
  }
```

please tell me the right answwer about my question